# Start an Activity from Item (ActionBar)?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar-compat

I'm using ActionBarCompat to make an actionbar for devices under API 11.
It works great and was easy to setup, but I'm stuck.

I have some items on the Actionbar, and it looks great.
Some Items are behind the three dots (ifRoom) and some you always can see.

How do I make so when you click on one of these items so it starts an new Activity?
I tried with switch/case and other methods, but didnt work to send from one Activity to another through the Items. I know how to send from button, imagebutton to another Activity, but not from Items.

My main.xml looks like this:

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:title="Lägg till"
    android:icon="@drawable/new"    
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    budsnabben:showAsAction="always"/>
```

And the code in MainActivity looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case R.id.menu_item2:
        // another startActivity, this is for item with id "menu_item2"
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

The problem is on case R.id.... After Id, I dont get my class map or main, its not there.

Thank you.

**SOLUTION:**

Just want to thank you Gerard.

I created new Strings in strings.xml.
After that, I did change the title in my main.xml to this:

`android:title="@string/add"`

I did hard-coded that line like before, therefore it didn't work I think:

`android:title="@+id/add"`

Thank you once more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { ... }` in your activity using the actionbar and create a switch-case matching `item.getItemId()` with the IDs from the menu layout. After that creating the appropriate intent like you would on a regular button.

Comment: Please add the action bar layout, you may have an error in your ID declaration